# Network.connection shows unknown

Tags: plugins, ionic2

I have a function which returns true or false based upon the connection.

```
nullConnection() {
    return (Network.connection === 'none');
  }
```

> when i print `console.log(this.nullConnection());` it shows me **`false`**
>   when i print `console.log(Network.connection);` it shows me **`unknown`** I am getting unknown and false all the time even when my internet is connected i am getting only this.

What i am expecting is when i am connected with internet my console.log(network.connection); should print `wifi` but i am getting unknown.

Answer (score 0):

When you use native plugin 'Network', you can not check it on browser. please use real devices Android and inspect it (chrome://inspect/#devices).